# HTTP response is never returned

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, httprequest

I am building an app in Xamarin.Android ! which determines my Address using google Maps API when given a latitude and longitude. However my App fails to deliver an HTTP response. I don't receive any runtime errors and VS debugger behaves as if my App has hanged.

1> I don't know whether this is an issue of Xamarin.Android

2> *As i read somehwere it could be an issue of blocking,asynchronous codes but then I use the same piece of code for my Windows App and it never gave me trouble*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App_Code
{
public class myLocationProxy
{
    public static async Task<RootObject_AutoLocationAddress> getmyLocation(string lat, string lng)
    {


        var http = new HttpClient();    
       /*CODE STOPS HERE*/var response = await http.GetAsync(String.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false", Uri.EscapeDataString(lat), Uri.EscapeDataString(lng)));         
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject_AutoLocationAddress));

        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));

        var data = (RootObject_AutoLocationAddress)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

        return data;
    }
}


[DataContract]
public class AddressComponent_AutoLocationAddress
{
   [DataMember]
    public string long_name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Result_AutoLocationAddress
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<AddressComponent_AutoLocationAddress> address_components { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string formatted_address { get; set; }

}
[DataContract]
public class RootObject_AutoLocationAddress
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Result_AutoLocationAddress> results { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string status { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: How do you call that async method? Try adding `.ConfigureAwait(false);` on your awaited calls to `HttpClient`.

Comment: @Cheesebaron  Strange I tried it a while ago and it didn't work. Thanks mate

Comment: Are you sure it's not returning at all? for my experience when a request fails on Xamarin.Android it can take as much as 3 minutes to end the request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code snippet just added `TimeOut` value.

```
public static async Task<RootObject_AutoLocationAddress> getmyLocation(string lat, string lng)
{
       var client = new HttpClient() 
       { 
         Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000) //10 second, This line might help you
       };

       var response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false", Uri.EscapeDataString(lat), Uri.EscapeDataString(lng)));         
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject_AutoLocationAddress));

        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));

        var data = (RootObject_AutoLocationAddress)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

        return data;
}
```

Cheers!!